# Error while generating IPA using Bamboo CI

Tags: ios, build, continuous-integration, bamboo

I am using Local Bamboo CI for generating IPA file. Bamboo job is able to fetch the project from Git repository and Build it successfully but while exporting it for IPA file, i am getting issue with the Path.

11-Aug-2016 14:23:50    Validate /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StackApp-cmvkahtnfpsmywcecbxrmhrwzekn/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/StackApp.app
11-Aug-2016 14:23:50        cd /Users/admin/Movies/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/STAC-TEST-JOB1
11-Aug-2016 14:23:50        export PATH="/Applications/Xcode7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin"
11-Aug-2016 14:23:50        export PRODUCT_TYPE=com.apple.product-type.application
11-Aug-2016 14:23:50        builtin-validationUtility /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StackApp-cmvkahtnfpsmywcecbxrmhrwzekn/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/StackApp.app -validate-for-store
11-Aug-2016 14:23:50
11-Aug-2016 14:23:50    ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
11-Aug-2016 14:23:50
11-Aug-2016 14:23:50    error: Specified application doesn't exist or isn't a bundle directory : '/Users/admin/Movies/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/STAC-TEST-JOB1/builds/StackApp.app'

Below is the Job setting related to build:

[image]

New Config:

[image]

ld: framework not found Pods_StackApp

build   19-Aug-2016 11:42:18    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

19-Aug-2016 11:42:18    ** BUILD FAILED **
19-Aug-2016 11:42:18
19-Aug-2016 11:42:18
19-Aug-2016 11:42:18    The following build commands failed:
19-Aug-2016 11:42:18            Ld build/StackApp.build/Release-iphoneos/StackApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/StackApp normal armv7
19-Aug-2016 11:42:18            Ld build/StackApp.build/Release-iphoneos/StackApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/StackApp normal arm64
19-Aug-2016 11:42:18    (2 failures)
19-Aug-2016 11:42:18    Failing task since return code of [/usr/bin/xcodebuild clean build -sdk iphoneos9.3 -alltargets CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/admin/Movies/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/STAC-ABC-JOB1/build] was 65 while expected 0

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and solved it in that way.

iOS application path set to ${bamboo.build.working.directory}/build/
(be aware that there is no file name for this, it is only a path)

yhan in the Custom Parameters (for xcodebuild) set CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${bamboo.build.working.directory}/build

this worked for me.

If you would get error with exporting the archive in the next step than you can set also -archivePath ${bamboo.build.working.directory}/build/[yourappname] in the Custom Parameters for xcodebuild

Comment: I have updated my question with the new changes as you said but then i am getting build failure now.

Comment: can you add the error here. Because, after setting up those, it might be required that other settings should be adjusted.

Comment: I have updated the question with the log and screenshot of the Config - Heading "New Config"

Comment: I can not exactly read the error, but I have the experience, the error tells you exactly the command which causes it. What I have done ist, I opened an terminal window to the JOB Directory and set exactly the written command in the error as command line and I got in the command line the exact error from xcodebuild. May be this could help you also

in my case for example was the ipa type wrong, I wanted ad-hoc but tried to build appstore. In terminal xcodebuild told me exactly this and I could change